# rails geocoder gem query shows different nearby results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am using the geocoder gem to show nearby results from the current IP address. The problem is that geocoder shows nearby locations correctly only when I use wifi, otherwise I can see other locations that are not within 5 miles on 4g.

```
def index 
    location_info = request.location
    @locations = Location.near([location_info.latitude, location_info.longitude], 5)
end
```

The results are different and when I check the database  `rails console` to see what the locations ip address is. I realised that cellular networks deal requests through their own network. Wifi on the other hand uses my own private network which means a different ip address in the `ip_address` param. Thus producing different results from the query above. I could be wrong but thats my assumption.

Does anyone know if there is another way to get the same results on both wifi and through a cellular network on nearbys?

Comment: i think that you have to use html5 geolocation to get really accurate results. Getting location based on IP address, as you have shown, is troublesome.

Comment: @Mohammed probably sometime it may depends on your 4G service provider's network locations.
But I also need the exact answer or solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ip address used for wifi and cellular network. So this problem occurred.